# Font color of disabled listbox

Tags: windows, listview, colors, listbox

I want to draw some listview items disabled and would like to mimic the appearance of a disabled standard Windows listbox. Which colors does it use?
I can't find anything in my [reference chart](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/12/6648399.aspx) :-) or with Google.

**Edit:** Shortly after posting the obvious occurred to me - it seems to be COLOR_GRAYTEXT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question to be able to close that issue (i.e. accept an answer).

A disabled windows listbox draws clGrayText on clWindow/COLOR_GRAYTEXT on COLOR_WINDOW.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just disable it and it will show browser default, and my guess is IE uses the same style as Windows (if not, a screenshot would be nice..)

```
<select disabled/><option...
```

Like this:
Disabled select

Comment: Do you know a possibility to post an attachment on stackoferflow?